# After the second commit to GitHub

Tags: github, deployment, angular5

I have done my first commit to GitHub and deployed on GitHub pages and it was published successfully. After that I did some modifications on Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) files and pushed to GitHub but when I view the app, as previously, it didn't show the updates. So I downloaded the repository and ran using Angular CLI. It displayed with updates.

What should I do to view on GitHub pages, my updated app?

This is my published app's URL: https://denukanirmalee.github.io/ang2/

Comment: you have to push your commit ;)

Comment: yeah i have done so. repository has updated and that shows the updated output. but i want to update the deployed output too. i mean which opens in browser

Comment: you have to push the gh-pages branch in the repo

Comment: i posted it as a detailed answer hope it will help

Comment: Hi hasib, it doesn't work.  https://denukanirmalee.github.io/ang2/ shows nothing :(

Comment: since it is in the `ang2` directory you will have to use the command `ng build --prod --base-href /ang2/` all other commands are the same. try that

Comment: by directory i mean path otherwise assets paths will point towards denukanirmalee.github.io/ after the above command it point to denukanirmalee.github.io/ang2/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to host an angular app into github pages. you have to push your production code to `gh-pages` branch.

for this first build your code to production by

```
ng build --prod --base-href /PROJECT_NAME/
```

since it is ang2 in your case

```
ng build --prod --base-href /ang2/
```

then push the code in `dist` to `gh-pages` branch. there are npm packages to automate this. for example [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages)

```
npm install gh-pages -g
gh-pages -d dist
```

now you will have your code available in github pages.